# php update array values

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays with different length, but keys are similar.
My requirement is update $array1 with values of $array2 similar keys

```
$array1 = array("Jan"=>"0", "Feb"=>"0", "Mar"=>"0", "Apr"=>"0");

$array2 = array("Jan"=>"2", "Mar"=>"3");
```

Output:

```
$res = array("Jan"=>"2","Feb"=>"0","Mar"=>"3","Apr"=>"0");
```

Comment: try `$array2+$array1`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve it by this code:

```
$array1 = array("Jan" => "0", "Feb" => "0", "Mar" => "0", "Apr" => "0");

$array2 = array("Jan" => "2", "Mar" => "3");

$array3 = array_replace($array1, $array2);
print_r($array3);
```

Comment: You can use existing $array1 instead of $array3, if you don't want to create new array.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.Maha Dev

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

Comment: output from your code is `Array ( [Jan] => 2 [Feb] => 0 [Mar] => 3 )` can you explain why `array_unique`?

Comment: but the output should be `$res = array("Jan"=>"2","Feb"=>"0","Mar"="3","Apr"=>"0");` as per question

Comment: array_unique will remove all duplicate elements having same value. 0 in this case for Feb and Apr.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `+` operator.

```
$array1 = array("Jan"=>"0","Feb"=>"0","Mar"=>"0","Apr"=>"0");
$array2 = array("Jan"=>"2", "Mar"=>"3");
print_r($array2 + $array1);
```

[DEMO](https://eval.in/489482)